# How can I have mocha reporter for protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor, mocha.js, jasmine-spec-reporter

I'm using protractor (0.22.0) for testing my app.
Is this possible to have a mocha-style reporter instead of the basic jasmine one?
It currenlty looks like this:

```
(....F...)
```

And I'm looking something more like:

```
my set of tests 1
  my test 1-1
  my test 1-2
my set of tests 2
  my test 2-1
  my test 2-2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Jasmine reporter in Protractor tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677986/custom-jasmine-reporter-in-protractor-tests)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the response here: [Custom Jasmine reporter in Protractor tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677986/custom-jasmine-reporter-in-protractor-tests)

I'm using this module and it works perfectly: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Frameworks](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/frameworks.md) Protractor docs. Once you've installed Mocha, you can set Mocha options in your `.protractor.conf.js` file:

```
mochaOpts: {
  reporter: "spec",
}
```

Comment: The thing is I don't want to switch framework. I'm doing good with Jasmine. All I want is change the reporter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tap file. Its pretty good. https://github.com/proverma/tap-file

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if mocha reporters work with Jasmine, but there are some other Jasmine reporters that work better than the default reporter.

You need to require jasmine-reporters. It's required to have it as a dependency. Then you can call any of [Jasmine Reporters listed here](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters/tree/master/src) in your `onPrepare` function inside your protractor config object.

```
npm i --save-dev jasmine-reporters
```

Using `TapReporter` for example. Do this inside your `protractor.config.js`:

```
  onPrepare: function() {
    // The require statement must be down here, since jasmine-reporters
    // needs jasmine to be in the global and protractor does not guarantee
    // this until inside the onPrepare function.
    require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
      new jasmine.TapReporter());
  },
```

#### For Jasmine 2.x and Protractor >1.6

```
  framework: "jasmine2",

  onPrepare: function() {
    // The require statement must be down here, since jasmine-reporters
    // needs jasmine to be in the global and protractor does not guarantee
    // this until inside the onPrepare function.
    var TapReporter = require('jasmine-reporters').TapReporter;

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new TeamCityReporter());
  }
```