# Custom Jasmine reporter in Protractor tests

Tags: jasmine, protractor, jasmine-spec-reporter

I can not find how to change reporter style in protractors runner using jasmine framework.

What I have right now is:

[image]

But I would like something more like:

[image]

**Is there a way to add custom reporter for jasmine that would show current test running instead of DOTS and Fs?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am building a jasmine reporter that does exactly what you want, [jasmine-spec-reporter](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter).

---

To configure in protractor.conf.js:

```
onPrepare: function(){
    var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({displayStacktrace: 'all'}));
}
```

Comment: jasmine-spec-reporter has become the industry standard way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Add the isVerbose flag to the protractor config, it's false by default:

```
exports.config = {
  . . .

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    isVerbose: true
  }
};
```

Comment: This only helps partially as it is holding output till all tests end. Since I have e2e tests that run realllly long I would like to know what test has what status. Right now I found that I can add my own custom reporter and I hope to share it later..

Comment: Would love to see how you are doing this, if you get a spare moment to share.

Comment: @VytautasButkus did you ever make anything to share?

Comment: @BillyMoon I did, but never to the level that it would be sharable.. Though I dropped it and used the one that suggested.

Comment: This does not work with the protractor 2.5.1 since that is not a valid jasmine option at this time.

Answer (score 4):

Add this dependency to your project:
`npm install jasmine-spec-reporter --save-dev`

And add this to your config file:

```
onPrepare: function(){
    var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({displayStacktrace: 'all'}));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To extend @fer's answer:

You can add these settings to `jasmineNodeOpts` to both see the current test and get stack trace right when test fails:

```
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    isVerbose: true,
    realtimeFailure: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  },
```