# Jasmine with promises not showing test results

Tags: node.js, jasmine, promise

So I have a very basic test where I want to check the type of a Promise response in a test using Jasmine. I'm running a node project and have all of those details set up

```
describe('fail assertion', function() {
        it('should be a failure', function(done) {
            myvideopromise.then(function(resp) {
                expect(true).toBe(false);
                done();
            }).catch(done);
        });
    });

describe('list videos', function() {
        it('should return a list of videos', function(done) {
            myvideopromise.then(function(videos) {
                expect(Array.isArray(videos)).toBe(true);
                done();
            }).catch(done);
        });
    });
```

But when I run it I just see this below.

```
Started
F.

Failures:
1) video suite fail assertion should be a failure
  Message:
    Expected true to be false.
```

The "F" is red and the "." is green. So it seems like it's properly running the test assertions, but for successes it doesn't seem to be showing the success message. Is there a flag I need to pass or something? I'm calling it using

```
jasmine JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH=test/jasmine_config.json
```

And my *jasmine_config.json* file simply looks like

```
{
    "spec_dir": "test/other/",
    "spec_files": [
        "video_tests.js"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Jasmine reporter in Protractor tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677986/custom-jasmine-reporter-in-protractor-tests)

Comment: I tried setting those fields to true and they don't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('fail assertion', function () {
        it('should be a failure', function (done) {
            myvideopromise.then(function (resp) {
                expect(true).toBe(true);
                done();
            }).catch(e => {
                done(e);
            });
        });
    });

  describe('list videos', function () {
        it('should return a list of videos', function (done) {
            myvideopromise.then(function (videos) {
                expect(Array.isArray(videos)).toBe(true);
                done();
            }).catch(e => {
                done(e);// it's a failure case
            });
        });
    });
```